# Name of card game of lowest sum in four cards with half-blind trading

Tags: identify-this-game

Each player is dealt 4 cards face down, 3 cards are placed in line and the fourth card is placed horizontally on the top of the other 3. Each player will take a card from the deck and replace any of the 3 bottom cards from left to right.

The goal is to keep the lowest value in these 3 cards, Joker is -1, and starting from number 10 each hand this number will be zero, in the first hand 10=0, second 9=0 and so on. Once the deck of cards is empty, each player shows the total value in the 3 cards, the fourth card then is shown by putting in your forehead, and then negotiate to exchange your card from the other players. trying to steal the lowest nomination, the player with the lowest amount of points wins and the number of cards for this player decrease by one. The player who finishes with 1 card wins.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [Golf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golf_(card_game)) variation.

This is a mix of the card game [Golf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golf_(card_game)) / [Cabo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cabo_(game)) with [Blind Man's Bluff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blind_man%27s_bluff_(poker)) added for the final deduction/bluffing/betting/negotiation round, plus the addition of the two series elements, zero cards and hand size reduction.

I can't find any reference to a specific game/name with this combination, however.